# keyup function to prompt an error whenever user input the wrong length

Tags: angular, typescript

so i have an array of number [5,8,10], and i want the user to input the number in the form. I also want to use the (keyup) to prompt an error message whenever the user input the length of number other than 5,8 or 10. The message is simply "Wrong number length" with red colour. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = [5, 8, 10];
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;
```

you have to add local reference #myInput to your input in html. and create an observable in your typescripts after ngOnInit. for example ngAfterViewInit.

```
const inputText$ = fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
                        debounceTime(500),
                        map(event => event as KeyboardEvent),
                        map(event => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value),
                        distinctUntilChanged(),
                      );
inputText$.subscribe(text => {
                    if (this.myArray.indexOf(text.length) !== -1) {
                      showError();
                     }
                    });
```